# Including non-breaking whitespace in character classes

Tags: regex, raku

In Perl6, no-break space is considered space, so

```
say 'Perl 6' ~~ /   /   # Please understand there's a no-break space in the middle
```

produces

```
Null regex not allowed
```

Solution is to quote the character, like so

```
say 'Perl 6' ~~ / ' ' / ; # OUTPUT: «｢ ｣␤»
```

However, that does not work if you want to include a non-breaking space into a character class:

```
$str ~~ /<[ & < > " ' {   ]>/ )
```

I could use [`Zs`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Adverbs), which is a space separator, but that one seems more broad... Any other way?
Quoting does not help, either. Question is, what character class should I use there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
$str ~~ /<[ & < > " ' { \xA0 ]>/
```

or more readable:

```
$str ~~ /<[ & < > " ' { \c[NO-BREAK SPACE] ]>/
```